# Android SSL certificate conversion

Tags: android, ssl

I want use android HTTPS connection. I have SSL certificate in .crt format but android needs .bks format how can I convert this certificate format in ubuntu

Comment: the question is duplicated , see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284466/how-to-convert-cer-to-bks

Answer (score 1):

Steps:-

1. Convert ".crt" to ".cer - (Base 64)" via Windows OS or any other source.
2. Download  "Bouncy Castle provider" (bcprov-jdkxx-xxx.jar) from http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html
3. Use following cmd to convert ".cer" generated to ".bks" format :-

"pathOfJRE/bin/keytool_here" -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file ".cerFilePath_here" -alias myAlias -keystore "pathToStoreGeneratedBKSfile_here" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "downloadedBouncyCastleProviderLocation_here" -storetype BKS -storepass "bksFilePassword_here"

******Example******
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\keytool" -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "C:\Users\chetan\Desktop\Pravin-123/abc_prod.cer" -alias myAlias -keystore "C:\Users\chetan\Desktop\Pravin-123/abc_tbu__prod.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "C:\Users\chetan\Desktop\Pravin-123\bcprov-jdk15on-155.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass "abc!Tbu@app123"

---

4. Verify the .bks file generated, cmd :-

"pathOfJRE/bin/keytool_here" -list -keystore "pathOfeGeneratedBKSfile_here" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath ""downloadedBouncyCastleProviderLocation_here" -storetype BKS -storepass "bksFilePassword_here"

******EXAMPLE*****
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\keytool" -list -keystore "C:\Users\chetan\Desktop\Pravin-123/abc_tbu__prod.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "C:\Users\chetan\Desktop\Pravin-123\bcprov-jdk15on-155.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass ""abcTbu@app123"

---

5. use this bks file in android. Place it in raw folder and give its path to Secure httpUrlConnection

-Ref:
 http://transoceanic.blogspot.in/2011/11/android-import-ssl-certificate-and-use.html ,

https://github.com/ikust/hello-pinnedcerts

Answer (score 0):

To generate the `.bks` file, you need:

- openssl
- sed
- keytool (comes with JAVA)
- Bouncy Castle Jar - [Link to File](http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk15on-155.jar)

Now perform the following steps:

**Obtain server's public self-signed certificate:**

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect [SERVER_URL]:443 2>&1 | \
  sed -ne "/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p" > [Certificate_file_name].pem
```

**Generate .bks file using a pass phrase**

```
keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "[Certificate_file_name].pem" \
  -alias [Alias_name] -keystore "[BKS_file_name].bks" \
  -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider \
  -providerpath "[DOWNLOADED_JAR_FILE_PATH]" -storetype BKS -storepass [Pass_phrase]
```

**Confirm that the file is created**

```
keytool -list -keystore "[BKS_file_name].bks" \
  -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider \
  -providerpath "[DOWNLOADED_JAR_FILE_PATH]" -storetype BKS -storepass [Pass_phrase]
```